# Game Studio Connect Timeout

Tags: networking, xna, vmware, xbox360, vmware-fusion

I realize this isn't exactly programming specific, so if this is not the place, I apologize in advance, and let me know so I can take the question down.

**Short Version**

When I try to connect to the Xbox via XNA Device Center, I get a timeout error message on the Xbox, and the Device Center lists the following:

`Initiated search on the local subnet for your Xbox 360 using the connection key you typed.

Found My Xbox at IP address 192.168.1.102.

Session created.
Connecting to My Xbox at IP address 192.168.1.102:1002...

Connected to 192.168.1.102:1002. Authenticating...`

**My Setup**

Windows 7 inside VMWare Fusion
Running on Macbook Pro
Wireless network

**Long Version**

I am using XNA Game Studio on my Mac via a VMWare Fusion Windows 7 install. I am a college student developing a senior thesis around a simulation that I will be programming on Xbox hardware via XNA.

My roommate has an Xbox which I started developing on with no problems. I then went home for winter break, and bought my own Xbox to work with, but ran into this timeout problem back home. I borrowed a Windows XP netbook, installed XNA, and it connected perfectly.

I'm now back at school, and it still won't connect. I don't think it is the network or the router, because it worked on my roommates Xbox just fine.

I'm getting desperate. I've already missed a committee deadline because of this, and a second one is looming around the corner. I need to get working, but every time I post this question, I get 60 something views but no responses. Please, anything at all, I really need the help!

Comment: Sorry Dave.  Never had any problems like this.  You need to swap out  different components to isolate which component is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wireless network is more than likely the culprit ... it works sometimes, I've had some success, but I've also seen some really funky errors that go away when you connect via hardwire to the same hub/router as the xbox.

I know you think it's not a likely problem, but just give it a try taking wireless out of the equation just to see if it works

Comment: That did it - I had to go buy a hundred foot long Ethernet cable, but it works! Thanks!